# Using route actions with new laravel route syntax

Tags: laravel, syntax, laravel-8

I have question about syntax which I can not find an answer for.

I have code in routes file:

```
Route::get(
    '/something/{seoString}/{someMore}',
    ['as' => 'my_name', 'uses' => '\my\namespace\MyController@index', 'my_route_action' => 20]
);
```

And I would like to rewrite it using the new syntax for calling controller

```
Route::get(
    '/something/{seoString}/{someMore}',
    [MyController@::class, 'index'] // would like to use this new syntax
);
```

And it works fine, but how can I add the custom route action 'my_route_action'?

I know it's possible to wrap the routes with a group and add it this way:

```
Route::group(['my_route_action' => 20], static function () {
    Route::get(
        '/something/{seoString}/{someMore}',
        [MyController@::class, 'index'] // would like to use this new syntax
    );
);
```

But that's not what I'm looking for. I don't want to be adding one group for each route just to add the route action.

So I wanted to ask if it does exist something like `->addCustomAction()` or how is this supposed to be done?

Comment: What is that `my_route_action` ? I never saw a _"custom route action"_. I can't find it in any part of the documentation. How would you access that data and why/how were you using that ?

Comment: You can access it using $request->route()->getAction()

Comment: @MarekBarta That produces `\my\namespace\MyController@index`, in what version of Laravel did that produce `['my_route_action' => 20]`?

Comment: @MarekBarta `request->route()->getAction()` would return `GET`, `POST`, `PUT`, `OPTIONS` or `DELETE` but not `my_route_action` or `20`...

Comment: @Ohgodwhy I wanted to add this key/value pair to the action array.

Comment: @matiaslauriti Illuminate\Routing\Route method getAction() Get the action array or one of its properties for the route. Its retturning an array in which I would like to add my key/value pair.

Comment: @MarekBarta the [method](https://github.com/laravel/framework/blob/277c2fbd0cebd2cb194807654d870f4040e288c0/src/Illuminate/Routing/Route.php#L867-L870) that sets the `action` only uses `uses` and `controller` but not your custom `index` in that array... Still, why were you trying or using that ? I never saw someone doing so, maybe you want to use other approach (Laravel way), but if you don't tell us how are you using it and why, we cannot help you "translate" your old route to the new way. We need more info as you are doing something that is not even documented.

Comment: Not meaning it bad. But I'm not looking for some other way to do it. I have code, which I have no control of and that code expects some data to be send that way.

Comment: @marekbarta but you still have to explain what is that `my_route_action` doing. We cannot help you unless you tell us how do you use that and where, because, again, you are doing something that is not documented, so we have no idea what you are trying to achieve if you do not explain it to us. Also, do not do `static function` for route group.

Comment: I'm trying to add some data to the array which is accessible by request->route()->getAction(). 'my_route_action ' was just a made up key, it might as well be 'data', 'something', 'anything' etc. The idea is to pass some extra data by route and not polluting url with it.

Comment: Also what is wrong with static function for route group?

Comment: @MarekBarta Could you find a way for doing that? I also have the same problem, it was supported in Laravel 5.x but not in 8.x+ and hard to explain people why you may need it. I'll appreciate your help if you could find a way to do it.

Comment: Yes thats right. Unfortunatelly I did not find a way to do it. So I abandoned the sulution and went to a different way completly.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the route action is not a thing, and probably shouldn't be. Unsure what you're actually trying to achieve with that too.

If you're passing in GET data like a bit of data, you can do it through: `{variable}` so the URL would become the following:

```
Route::get('my-route-url/{model}/get', [MyController::class, 'methodName')->name('something')->middleware(['something'])
```

And in your controller, you dependency inject request if you're wanting to use that too, as well as the model:

```
public function methodName(Request $request, Model $model)
{
    dd($request->all(), $model);
}
```

The "as" is the the name method. Middleware is still middleware.

If you're trying to do a Key/Pair bit of data, you need to use POST request and pass it in the data, which you can access via the `$request->input('keyName')` method in the controller.